# Selecting Date and ID from a table with max value of Amount

Tags: sql

I am trying to fetch the Date and VisitorID from a payment table having the maximum value of amount. I know how to find max value by each date but I am unable to fetch the Date and VisitorID having the maximum value of amount.

I tried to use the attached code below but I just get one value having max value. I am trying to get date and visitor ID from each day with maximum value of amount.

```
SELECT Date, visitorID
FROM payment
WHERE Amount = 
(
    SELECT MAX(Amount)
    FROM payment
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a subquery:

```
SELECT p1.Date, p1.visitorID
FROM payment p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Date, MAX(Amount) AS max_amount
    FROM payment
    GROUP BY Date
) p2
    ON p1.Date = p2.Date AND p1.Amount = p2.max_amount;
```

The subquery finds, for each date, the maximum amount.  Then, we join this to your original table to effectively filter off any record for a given date which does *not* have the maximum amount.

If your version of SQL supports analytic functions, then we can use them instead:

```
SELECT Date, visitorID
FROM
(
    SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Amount DESC) rn
    FROM payment p
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you also wanted to have all records for a given date which are tied for the highest amount, then replace `ROW_NUMBER` above with either `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: This works but can you help me understand the usage of Inner Join.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using correlated subquery

```
    SELECT Date, visitorID,amount
    FROM payment a
    WHERE exists
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM payment b where a.date=b.date group by b.date having max(b.amount)=a.amount
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your comments it seems you need `row_number()`

```
  with cte as 
   ( 
    SELECT *,row_number() over(partition by date order by amount desc)rn
   from payment t1
   ) select * from cte where cte.rn=1
```

Comment: I tried using this but it gives me multiple memberIDs for each date. I need just one with maximum value.

Comment: @RahulShroff do you need date wise each member max amoun?

Comment: @RahulShroff it would be nice if you could post sample data and its output

Comment: Exactly. I need date and memberID with the maximum value of amount from each date.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, you need reference from the `outerquery` to make it correlated `subquery` :

```
SELECT p.Date, p.visitorID
FROM payment p
WHERE p.Amount = (SELECT MAX(p1.Amount) FROM payment p1 WHERE p1.Date = p.Date);
```